# Was combing gauge fields into photon and $Z$ boson already considered before incorportating Higgs mechanism in Standard Model?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, higgs, history, electroweak

*Before* physicists had the idea to incorporate the Higgs mechanism in the Standard Model, was there already the idea to combine the gauge fields $B_{\mu}$, $W_{\mu}^1$, $W_{\mu}^2$, $W_{\mu}^3$ into $$Z_{\mu}=\cos{\theta_W}W_{\mu}^3-\sin{\theta_W}B_{\mu}$$ and $$A_{\mu}=\sin{\theta_W}W_{\mu}^3+\cos{\theta_W}B_{\mu}~?$$

Comment: See [this one](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/12510/significance-of-higgs-model-used-in-glashow-salam-weinberg-theory). Absolutely! six year's before Weinberg's 1967 idea of utilizing the Higgs mechanism, Glashow had already nicely sorted out the entire misnamed "Weinberg angle mixing" in 1961: S.L. Glashow, "Partial-symmetries of weak interactions". Nuclear Physics. 22 (4): 579–588. Aren't those answers adequate?

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos : many thanks for the answer and the references

Comment: The  epochal moment in Glashow's paper is section 4 (you must slug through the skewed language!) introducing weak hypercharge, weak mixing, and thanking Gell-Mann for the setup. Gell-Mann was *quite impressed* by this, at the time...